# Is "You have 1 new answer. See your responses." needed when navigating to the same question via email?

Tags: discussion, email

I don't post questions often or visit any of The Trilogy every day.  Therefore, I always check the "Notify daily..." option.  Then, the user flow looks like this:

1. An email arrives in the inbox. 
   New answer, cool!
2. Click question url.
3. "You have 1 new answer. See your
   responses."  Uhm... yeah, I know, just came in from the email you sent.
4. Close banner and read answer.

This isn't a big problem, but it's not the kind of design decision I've come to expect from Atwood and team.

Comment: @Adam: Is this supposed to be a joke?

Comment: @surfrbum: I don't know, it's your comment.  Why are you asking me?

Answer (score 2):

Guess what they could do is drop in a parameter in the URL in the emails so that if you click it, the site will know you've come from a link in the email and not need to repeat itself.

Comment: That's what I thought first too

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler than that?  What if I bookmark the page and come to it directly?

The logic should be something like:
If <user> has new answers/comments and they're only in regard to the page they are viewing, don't show the notification banner.

Or even easier:
Never show notification banner for items on the currently viewed page.

Comment: @GollyJer I'm not sure about the last suggestion, because sometimes I just want to see what's new in a question/answer thread.